# Design a PID controller for a MG=1.5

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller, phase-margin, gain-margin

Consider the following system:

[image]

I need to design a PID controller with a gain margin of 1.5 **for the disturbance P(s)**.

In order to have a certain gain margin I need to find the critical gain Ku, so that I can calculate Kr as

$$Kr=Ku/1.5$$

For this I usually do a frequency analysis over the open loop system to find Ku and \$\omega_u\$ as follows:

$$|G(j\omega)|=1$$
$$\phi=-\pi$$

What is the open loop for P(s) and how would you define Ti and Td of the PID controller?